# Valid JAR signature for JavaFX projects

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, javafx-2, maven-3

I've been working through various recipes to produce a runnable JAR file for a **JavaFX** project using a Maven POM.  Each of these Stackoverflow questions describes the same problem.  It is frustrating that there seems to be several different solutions for the same goal.

**problem**:

> java.lang.SecurityException: **Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes**

Error when executing a JAR file on the command line.  Although Netbeans can happily run the program and debug the program.

**diagnosis**

There are several Stackoverflow and forum questions about this (most helpful ones below).  Even though is a known problem I'm yet to find a clear solution to work with JavaFX.  The procedures described in these answers do NOT with the **JavaFxPackager** tool used to bundle-up your JavaFX JAR:

- ["Invalid signature file digest" error adding Janino package through Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468704/invalid-signature-file-digest-error-adding-janino-package-through-maven)
- [Error (org.codehaus.mojo) when adding persistence to Maven-Java-project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21952318/error-org-codehaus-mojo-when-adding-persistence-to-maven-java-project) ... This looks the most promising since it is also a JavaFX project.  Same error here so far.

**usual approach**:
The post popular answer for this question (255 votes at time of writing): works with ***non***-JavaFX modules in our project:

- ["Invalid signature file" when attempting to run a .jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999489/invalid-signature-file-when-attempting-to-run-a-jar) ...

However when we put the same plug-in in the POM that builds the JavaFX JAR file, we still get the: "***Invalid signature file digest*** ..." error.  Specifically, I placed the `<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>` first before and then after the JavaFxPackager exec rule.  The result is

- Maven gives the: "*Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes*..." error

**question*:

How does one manage to package a JavaFX application.  This is the POM `<build> section` Netbeans sets-up for JavaFX:

```
      <build>
          <resources>
             <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
             </resource>
          </resources>

          <plugins>
             <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.8</version>
                  <executions>
                      <execution>
                          <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                          <phase>package</phase>
                          <goals>
                              <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                          </goals>
                          <configuration>
                              <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                              <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                          </configuration>
                      </execution>
                  </executions>
              </plugin>

              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>1.3.2</version>
                  <executions>
                      <execution>
                          <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                          <phase>package</phase>
                          <goals>
                              <goal>exec</goal>
                          </goals>
                          <configuration>
                              <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                              <arguments>
                                  <argument>-createjar</argument>
                                  <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                                  <argument>-appclass</argument>
                                  <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                                  <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                                  <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                                  <argument>-outdir</argument>
                                  <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                                  <argument>-outfile</argument>
                                  <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                              </arguments>
                          </configuration>
                      </execution>
                      <execution>
                          <id>default-cli</id>
                          <goals>
                              <goal>exec</goal>
                          </goals>
                          <configuration>
                              <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                              <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
                          </configuration>
                      </execution>
                  </executions>
              </plugin>

              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.1</version>
                  <configuration>
                      <source>1.8</source>
                      <target>1.8</target>
                      <compilerArgument>-Xlint:unchecked</compilerArgument>  <!-- all -->
                      <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                      <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                      <compilerArguments>
                          <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib      /jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                      </compilerArguments>
                  </configuration>
              </plugin>

              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.16</version>
                  <configuration>
                      <additionalClasspathElements>
                          <additionalClasspathElement>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                      </additionalClasspathElements>
                  </configuration>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </build>
```

The `shard plugin` configuration used based on the answer in: ["Invalid signature file" when attempting to run a .jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999489/invalid-signature-file-when-attempting-to-run-a-jar) currently looks like this:

```
              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                      <!--    http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/     -->
                      <!--    http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Shade+Plugin -->
                      <!--    http://zhentao-li.blogspot.com.au/2012/06/maven-shade-plugin-invalid-signature.html     -->
                  <version>2.3</version>
                  <executions>
                      <execution>
                        <id>remove-sign-files</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                          <filters>
                              <filter>
                                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                  <excludes>
                                      <exclude>classes/META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                      <exclude>classes/META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                      <exclude>classes/META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                  </excludes>
                              </filter>
                          </filters>
                        </configuration>
                      </execution>
                  </executions>
              </plugin>
```

To keep Netbeans out of the equation as much as possible, I just run

- mvn package

On the command line.  This just issue seems to be a frequent problem and I'm hoping someone has cracked the code for JavFX bundling in other JAR files for a JavaFX build.

**Other links**:

- [How to tell the maven-shade-plugin to preserve signatures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779708/how-to-tell-the-maven-shade-plugin-to-preserve-signatures)
- [Packaging jar is invalid Aggregator project need pom as packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733729/packaging-jar-is-invalid-aggregator-project-need-pom-as-packaging)
- [Apache Maven Shade Plug-in](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)
- [Executable JAR](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738653/maven-shade-plugin-does-not-exclude-the-manifest-signature-files

Comment: Instead of `<exclude>classes/META-INF/*.SF</exclude>` try `<exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had a very similar problem; when I included a signed JAR (bouncycastle) in the project. Its signature was repackaged verbatim, resulting in an obvious SecurityException:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for
>   Manifest main attributes

Filtering of all sorts failed; the solution that works for me looks like this in the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.8</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <excludes>META-INF/*.SF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.RSA</excludes>
        ...
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I omitted some lines after the new one with the "excludes" pattern.
This single line was the solution for me - I include the other lines so you can see the placement. (I had trouble with many other postings which omitted the context of a tag, so I try to save others this trouble).

Hope that helps others with the same problem.

Comment: Finally! I've been suffering for hours with de shade plugin to no avail.

Comment: I know the feeling - it motivated me to write this answer.

Comment: by the way - if a JAR is signed, there is usually a reason why it is. Consider whether distributing/installing the JAR separately instead of repackaging makes sense. For a Crypto Provider like BouncyCastle, there are some good reasons why you should try to keep it separately and signed.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of research I found a solution that works for my project using JavaFX, Maven and NetBeans.

I'm working on a simple REST client that uses jersey and moxy to decode JSON. 
After adding the dependency jersey-media-moxy application reports the error of invalid signature.

I found that this depends on the presence of the signature file **ECLIPSE_.RSA** and **ECLIPSE_.SF** inside the META-INF for some libraries. 
In my case were the `org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.5.0.jar`, `org.eclipse.persistence.antlr-2.5.0.jar`, `org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.5.0.jar` and `org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.5.0.jar`

The pom.xml in Netbeans that you indicated running two separate step.
The first invoke maven-dependency-plugin that expands all the external jar.
The second use exec-maven-plugin that call javafxpackager to create the final jar file e finally run it.

By performing the two steps in sequence signature in org.eclipse libraries are placed in the META-INF of the final jar file and this generates the error on the signature.

My solution is add an intermediate step between the execution of the maven-dependency-plugin and exec-maven-plugin. In this step I'm going to delete all signature file inside the directory

```
${project.build.directory}/classes
```

To do this I used a plugin maven-antrun-plugin

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
         <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                   <goal>run</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                   <target>
                       <delete>
                           <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/classes" includes="**/META-INF/*.DSA"/>
                           <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/classes" includes="**/META-INF/*.RSA"/>
                           <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/classes" includes="**/META-INF/*.SF"/>
                    </delete>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```