# java.lang.SecurityException thrown while executing jar file

Tags: java, maven

I have an automation suite built using testng and maven. My pom file is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ca.nextgen.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>Automation_Framework_NewUI</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Automation_Framework_NewUI</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-mime4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>bsh</groupId>
            <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.1_3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-jxpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-jxpath</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.cssparser</groupId>
            <artifactId>cssparser</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-gwt</artifactId>
            <version>12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit-core-js</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ini4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>ini4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jr</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jr-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20080701</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
            <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
            <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
            <version>0.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.5-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.w3c.css</groupId>
            <artifactId>sac</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
            <artifactId>saxon</artifactId>
            <version>8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
            <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SaxonLiaison.jar needs to be downlaoded -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.26.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.26.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.26.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
             <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
              <version>2.41.2</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>serializer</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.testng</groupId> <artifactId>testng</artifactId> 
            <version>6.0.1</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webbitserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>webbit</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>




        <!-- JSON Path parameterization related jars -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
            <plugins>

                <!-- Following plugin executes the testng tests -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>TestFile.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            <!-- <suiteXmlFile>suites-test-testng.xml</suiteXmlFile> -->
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <!--  /configuration-->
                    <!-- configuration-->
        <filters>
            <filter>
                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </filter>
    </filters>
    <!-- Additional configuration. -->
</configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Compiler plugin configures the java version to be usedfor compiling 
                    the code -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>com.ca.nextgen.project.webservice.testcase.AutomationTest</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                        <transformer
                                implementation="com.github.edwgiz.mavenShadePlugin.log4j2CacheTransformer.PluginsCacheFileTransformer"/>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>onejar</shadedClassifierName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.github.edwgiz</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin.log4j2-cachefile-transformer</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I was able to create the jar file but when i run it throws me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:286)
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:239)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:317)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:348)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:415)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(URLClassPath.java:775)
        at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Resource.java:77)
        at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Resource.java:160)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Comment: maybe this will help you [Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes exception while trying to run jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855649/invalid-signature-file-digest-for-manifest-main-attributes-exception-while-tryin)

Comment: But how do i know which jar is signed or not? There are so many jars in my dependency.

Comment: This issue was resolved after I removed the .rsa and .sf files from the MANIFEST folder