# excluding dependency signature files in JAR file using build.sbt in IntelliJ

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I am having an issue similar to [Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes exception while trying to run jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855649/invalid-signature-file-digest-for-manifest-main-attributes-exception-while-tryin) but cannot get this or a number of other fixes to work using build.sbt and building the artifacts from IntelliJ 2018.1

The project was started in IntelliJ as a scala>sbt project
Java version is 1.8.0_77

My build.sbt contains:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.1.0",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.3.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.3.0",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.7.4",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.7.1"
)

excludeFilter in Compile := "*.SF" || "*.DSA" || "*.RSA"
```

The project builds without any error and runs fine in IntelliJ but when I Build> Build Artifacts and run the resulting jar from the command-line on the same machine as IntelliJ is running on:

java -jar myApp.jar

I get:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Comment: how are  your artifacts in IntelliJ defined?

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't address how to make the exclusion from IntelliJ but this will remove the files from the jar.

```
zip -d <jar file name>.jar META-INF/*.RSA META-INF/*.DSA META-INF/*.SF
```