# IntelliJ Jar Error : Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, java-8, executable-jar

I'm using `IntelliJ` IDE on an `armx64 linux-based` system, where i'm working on a ***non-maven*** java project that have a lot of modules (dependencies) linked to it. When running my project from the IDE everything works fine, however when building it into a runnable jar file and trying to run the jar from the terminal, using `java -jar myjar.jar`, i got the following error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:330)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:263)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:318)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:230)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:383)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:450)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(URLClassPath.java:977)
    at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Resource.java:77)
    at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Resource.java:160)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:454)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

I'm currently using OpenJdk-1.8, i tried to use Oracle JDK v1.8 instead to build and then rerun the jar file, but still facing the same error. I'd also tried to create a new simple "Hello world" application and export a corresponding jar for it where it runs successfully without errors.

Here is my jar internal structure and the corresponding manifist file:
[jar structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Avod.png)

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34856095/2960034

Comment: thanks a lot  @y.bedrov i realized that i have to exclude signed jars from my modules but i'm not using maven or even ant to build my jar so after reading the answer i solved the problem by deleting the signature files from my Meta-inf folder inside my jar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for ***@y.bedrov*** who linked to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34856095/2960034) that helped my solving the error, where it includes the following:

> "sqljdbc4.jar" was the signed JAR in OP's external libraries. So,
>   following above approach to systematically exclude the signature
>   related files like .SF, .RSA or .DES or other algorithms files is the
>   right way to move forward.

And yes I'm also using "sqljdbc4.jar", so after reading the answer i decided to solve the problem by deleting the signature files from my Meta-inf folder inside my jar file.