# Why Beeline gives an error when adding new UDF Java file to Hive AUX directory?

Tags: java, maven, hive, user-defined-functions

I've created a Maven Java Project to encrypt Hive column using Java UDF as in the below guides:

http://diginbigdata.blogspot.com/2017/01/hive-udf-example-encrypt-decrypt-data_28.html

https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.1.0/using-hiveql/topics/hive_create_udf.html

However when I built the project artifacts and added the JAR file to the configured AUX JAR directory, I receive the following error when I start Beeline:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:286)
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:239)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:317)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:348)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:415)
        at sun.misc.JarIndex.getJarIndex(JarIndex.java:137)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:674)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:666)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(URLClassPath.java:665)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:638)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:366)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:356)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:355)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:332)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:198)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Unable to determine Hadoop version information.
'hadoop version' returned:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:286)
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:239)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:317)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:348)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:415)
        at sun.misc.JarIndex.getJarIndex(JarIndex.java:137)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:674)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:666)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(URLClassPath.java:665)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:638)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:366)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:356)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:355)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:332)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:198)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I also used the solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855649/invalid-signature-file-digest-for-manifest-main-attributes-exception-while-tryin) to exclude signed JARs but still same error.

Here is my `Encypt.java` file:

```
package com.mycompany;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;

public class Encrypt extends UDF {

    public String evaluate(String input) {
        try {
            byte[] password = new String("abcdefghijklmnol").getBytes();
            // The password need to be 8, 16, 32 or 64 characters long to be used in AES encryption
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(password, "AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
            String output = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes()));
            return output;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is my `POM.XML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany.hiveudf</groupId>
    <artifactId>hiveudf</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <hadoop.version>2.6.0</hadoop.version>
        <hive.version>1.1.0</hive.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludes>META-INF/*.SF</excludes>
                            <excludes>META-INF/*.DSA</excludes>
                            <excludes>META-INF/*.RSA</excludes>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\lib\tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Note:** 
I don't know if it's related or not, but I'm using Kerbros and Sentry in my environment for security. So I use kinit to create a ticket before starting Beeline.