# Failsafe error: "Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes" when using shade plugin

Tags: maven, jar, maven-shade-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

When using shade-plugin in maven and later trying to run integration tests using failsafe-plugin, I get the following error when failsafe is about to run, resulting in my integration tests being skipped:

```
[ERROR] Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
```

This error seems to be caused by signed jars in dependencies. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34856095/2059662) suggests using dependency plugin to filter out the signatures, but it did not seem to work for me. Shade-plugin just unpacked all the dependencies and did not solve the problem. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 19):

Filtering out the signatures seems to be the right approach, but can (and perhaps should) be done directly in shade-plugin, without needing any other plugins. This is [implicitly documented on shade-plugins website](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html), where it talks about artifact filters. I made sure my shade-plugin execution included the following filters, and it worked:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <filters>
          <filter>
            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
              <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
              <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </filter>
        </filters>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: How was this different than what you had originally?

Comment: From memory, I tried filtering in the POM (excuse lack of detail, some time has passed)

Comment: there is a good example here too: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/data-flow/data-flow-tutorial/develop-apps-locally/create-fat-jars.htm

Comment: 2024 still works!