# Quarkus project not getting build

Tags: java, quarkus

I am trying to build my quarkus project but it is giving me below expectation, as I am new to it I am not getting exactly what is the problem. Please help me out, I have tried many thing like excluding but nothing works.

```
2021-02-22 17:36:59,100 ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#registerBeans threw an exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
    at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:336)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:269)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:273)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:230)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:759)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:840)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.JarClassPathElement$1$1$1.apply(JarClassPathElement.java:123)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.JarClassPathElement$1$1$1.apply(JarClassPathElement.java:118)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.JarClassPathElement.withJarFile(JarClassPathElement.java:161)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.JarClassPathElement.access$100(JarClassPathElement.java:35)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.JarClassPathElement$1$1.getData(JarClassPathElement.java:118)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(QuarkusClassLoader.java:332)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(QuarkusClassLoader.java:353)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanArchives.index(BeanArchives.java:259)
```

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like you have a signed jar in your dependencies. When this jar is packed in your jar, java cannot verify it. You have to exclude this jar and use it via classpath.

Maybe you also find some useful information in this post: [Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes exception while trying to run jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855649/invalid-signature-file-digest-for-manifest-main-attributes-exception-while-tryin)

Comment: Thank for your response, I have checked and tried that solution but no luck and I using so many maven.

Comment: Do you have any special files in your META-INF dircetory? Something like META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA and META-INF/*.RSA

Comment: No, it just have resource folder that's it.

Comment: I am getting error after this line: Downloading from googleapis: https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo/org/eclipse/scout/sdk/deps/org.eclipse.core.filesystem/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from sonatype-nexus-snapshots: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/eclipse/scout/sdk/deps/org.eclipse.core.filesystem/maven-metadata.xml

Comment: And in your test you excluded the api? Or set it to "provided" in Maven?

Comment: No I haven't excluded it, and not also set to provided,

Comment: The aproach was to set the jar as "provided" and put it in the classpath you use. So it isn't put in the uber-jar from quarkus.