# How do I build my IntelliJ IDEA project without getting a SecurityException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, paho, securityexception

I'm currently developing something, and I want to use the Eclipse Paho library in order to connect to an MQTT server. The problem is that whenever I build my project and run it (I run it on a Minecraft Spigot server, 1.16.5) I get the following error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:336) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:269) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:316) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:230) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:759) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:840) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getPluginDescription(JavaPluginLoader.java:165) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-400]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:148) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-400]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:389) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-400]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:206) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-400]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:931) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-400]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:173) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-400]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

I'm building using artifacts inside of IntelliJ IDEA. Here's the artifact I was using:

[image]

As you can see I extracted the Paho library into my output root. Could anybody help me solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes exception while trying to run jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855649/invalid-signature-file-digest-for-manifest-main-attributes-exception-while-tryin)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I found that question earlier. It sadly does not resolve my issue, since those solutions are all for Maven/Gradle/Ant and I build using artifacts (my build time with Maven is 25 seconds and with artifacts, it's about 3 seconds)