# Encountered an unexpected exception java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes while running my plugin

Tags: java, minecraft

```
[20:52:42] [Server thread/ERROR]: Encountered an unexpected exception
java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:340) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:282) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:321) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:762) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:845) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getPluginDescription(JavaPluginLoader.java:173) ~[spigot-api-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:144) ~[spigot-api-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_18_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:418) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3424-Spigot-7fbc6a1-bdac46b]
    at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.e(DedicatedServer.java:231) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3424-Spigot-7fbc6a1-bdac46b]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:994) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3424-Spigot-7fbc6a1-bdac46b]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:304) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3424-Spigot-7fbc6a1-bdac46b]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
```

help me plz.
I don't know what is wrong about my minecraft plugin

Comment: What did you do with the plugin ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes exception while trying to run jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855649/invalid-signature-file-digest-for-manifest-main-attributes-exception-while-tryin)

Comment: please go through once https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask