# Can't run created -jar file

Tags: java, maven, jar

I was creating jar file of my project. And every time when I trying to use it have same error

Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: no manifest section for signature file entry org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/JDKMessageDigest$RIPEMD256.class
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.verifySection(SignatureFileVerifier.java:608)
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:341)
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:263)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:318)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:230)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:383)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:450)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(URLClassPath.java:977)
        at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Resource.java:77)
        at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Resource.java:160)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:454)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)

pom file looks like this

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>XMLChangerTool</groupId>
    <artifactId>XMLChangerTool</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>META-INF/*.SF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.RSA</excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Already was trying solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855649/invalid-signature-file-digest-for-manifest-main-attributes-exception-while-tryin/34856095), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842559/valid-jar-signature-for-javafx-projects) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999489/invalid-signature-file-when-attempting-to-run-a-jar) questions, but it doesn't help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999489/invalid-signature-file-when-attempting-to-run-a-jar

Comment: @DushyantTankariya, stackoverflow thinks that it is comment cause of this symbols `/*`, it is typo mistake

Comment: @VinayPrajapati, add dependence, it doesn't help