# Java can't find ECIES, even through it's in the Bouncy Castle jar

Tags: java, bouncycastle, ecies

I'm trying to test-out ECIES, by adapting code from: https://gist.github.com/amrishodiq/9821413 and https://github.com/VictorThompson/t-encryption/blob/master/src/ECIESexample.java

I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting ECIES
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:540)
    at Ecies.encrypt(Ecies.java:51)
    at Ecies.main(Ecies.java:21)
```

even though ECIES is in the jar:

```
$ jar tvf bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar | grep ECIES
  4214 Sun Mar 01 12:03:08 GMT 2015 org/bouncycastle/crypto/kems/ECIESKeyEncapsulation.class
  1497 Sun Mar 01 12:03:08 GMT 2015 org/bouncycastle/crypto/parsers/ECIESPublicKeyParser.class
   795 Sun Mar 01 12:03:08 GMT 2015 org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/asymmetric/ec/IESCipher$ECIES.class
  1037 Sun Mar 01 12:03:08 GMT 2015 org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/asymmetric/ec/IESCipher$ECIESwithAES.class
  1108 Sun Mar 01 12:03:08 GMT 2015 org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/asymmetric/ec/IESCipher$ECIESwithAESCBC.class
  1046 Sun Mar 01 12:03:08 GMT 2015 org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/asymmetric/ec/IESCipher$ECIESwithDESede.class
  1117 Sun Mar 01 12:03:08 GMT 2015 org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/asymmetric/ec/IESCipher$ECIESwithDESedeCBC.class
```

What am I doing wrong?

Ecies.java:

```
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.security.spec.ECGenParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.IEKeySpec;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.IESParameterSpec;

public class Ecies {
    private SecureRandom random;
    private int keySize;
    private KeyPair akey;
    private KeyPair bkey;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Ecies ecies = new Ecies();
        byte[] plaintext = "Mary had a litle lamb.".getBytes();
        println("plaintext.length: " + plaintext.length);
        byte[] encrypted = ecies.encrypt(plaintext);
        println("encrypted.length: " + encrypted.length);
        byte[] decrypted = ecies.decrypt(encrypted);
        println("decrypted.length: " + decrypted.length);
        println("new String(decrypted): " + new String(decrypted));

    }

    public static void println(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    public Ecies () throws Exception{
        this.random = new SecureRandom();
    }

    public void establishKeys(String keysize) throws Exception {
        ECGenParameterSpec     ecGenSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec(keysize);
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");

        keyGen.initialize(ecGenSpec, random);

        this.akey = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        this.bkey = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        this.keySize = Integer.valueOf( (ecGenSpec.getName().substring(4, 7)) ).intValue();
    }


    public byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainText) throws Exception {
        // get ECIES cipher objects
        Cipher acipher = Cipher.getInstance("ECIES");

        //  generate derivation and encoding vectors
        byte[]  d = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        byte[]  e = new byte[] { 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
        IESParameterSpec param = new IESParameterSpec(d, e, 256);

        // encrypt the plaintext using the public key
        acipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new IEKeySpec(akey.getPrivate(), bkey.getPublic()), param);
        return acipher.doFinal(plainText);
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipherText) throws Exception {
        // get ECIES cipher objects
        Cipher bcipher = Cipher.getInstance("ECIES");

        //  generate derivation and encoding vectors
        byte[]  d = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        byte[]  e = new byte[] { 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
        IESParameterSpec param = new IESParameterSpec(d, e, 256);

        // decrypt the text using the private key
        bcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new IEKeySpec(bkey.getPrivate(), akey.getPublic()), param);
        return bcipher.doFinal(cipherText);
    }

    public byte[] sign(byte[] plainText) throws Exception {
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithECDSA");
        sig.initSign(akey.getPrivate());
        sig.update(plainText);
        return sig.sign();
    }

    public boolean verify(byte[] plainText, byte[] signature) throws Exception {
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithECDSA");
        sig.initVerify(akey.getPublic());
        sig.update(plainText);
        try {
            if (sig.verify(signature)) {
                return true;
            } else return false;
        } catch (SignatureException se) {
            System.out.println( "Signature failed" );
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int getKeySize() {
        return keySize;
    }

}
```

Makefile:

```
all: Ecies.class
    java -cp bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar:. Ecies

Ecies.class: clean
    javac -cp bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar Ecies.java 

clean:
    rm -f Ecies.class
```

Comment: You are not registering BC with JCA. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442012/whats-the-best-way-to-integrate-the-bouncy-castle-provider-in-a-java-program?rq=1) shows how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, that's one issue fixed.  If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.